# Remapping both Caps Lock and Windows keys to be separate modifiers

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, xmodmap, i3

I want to use both my <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key and <kbd>Windows</kbd> key in my i3wm config. In particular, I want <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to take the place of `$mod` in the config and I also want to be able to reference the <kbd>Windows</kbd> key in `bindsym`. How would I do this?

Currently, I'm able to use my <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key as `$mod` but I want to also use my <kbd>Windows</kbd> key now, as a different modifier.

My `.Xmodmap` is currently

```
clear Lock 
clear mod4

keycode 66 = Hyper_L
add mod4 = Hyper_L
```

and the keycode to my <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> key is 133.

Comment: Do you want to use the Windows key as the same modifier as CapsLock, as a different modifier, or as a non-modifier key?

Comment: A different modifier.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you are essentially removing the *Windows keys* from the modifier list with  `clear mod4`. In order to have *Caps Lock* available as an additional modifier instead as a replacement of the *Window keys*, you would have to set it to a different modifier. You can use modifiers `Mod1` through `Mod5` in addition to `Control`, `Shift` and `Mode_switch` with *i3*.

First check, if any modifiers are unused in the the layout you are using (without applying your `.Xmodmap`). You can get a list of the modifier settings with `xmodmap -pm`. For the `us` layout this returns (on my machine):

```
xmodmap:  up to 4 keys per modifier, (keycodes in parentheses):

shift       Shift_L (0x32),  Shift_R (0x3e)
lock        Caps_Lock (0x42)
control     Control_L (0x25),  Control_R (0x69)
mod1        Alt_L (0x40),  Alt_R (0x6c),  Meta_L (0xcd)
mod2        Num_Lock (0x4d)
mod3      
mod4        Super_L (0x85),  Super_R (0x86),  Super_L (0xce),  Hyper_L (0xcf)
mod5        ISO_Level3_Shift (0x5c),  Mode_switch (0xcb)
```

As you can see `mod3` is currently unused. In order to use it you just have to put the following into your `.Xmodmap`:

```
clear lock
keycode 66 = Hyper_R
add mod3 = Hyper_R
```

**Note:** In this case I used `Hyper_R` because `Hyper_L` was already bound to `mod4`. And 66 is the key code of *Caps Lock*. This may be different on your machine.

Now you can use this modifier with your *i3* keybindings. If you want to keep using the `$mod` variable with your configuration just set it to either `Mod3` or `Mod4` depending on if you want to use *Caps Lock* or the *Windows keys* for that. But There is no real need to actually use it (It is mainly convenience to ease up first time setup when choosing between *Alt* (`Mod1`) and *Windows keys* (`Mod4`).

Using the new Modifier is as simple as:

```
bindsym Mod3+s exec something
binysym Mod3+Mod4+s exec something_else
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Works great and I learned from this.